# Does deleting a Stack Exchange account delete all accounts using that OpenID?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

If I delete my Stack Exchange account then will it delete my all accounts? (E.g., Stack Overflow, Meta.Stack Overflow, etc.)

I want this because the system is buggy and opening account of someone else automatically that is completely wrong and made me frustrated.

Comment: Only those accounts you've marked for deletion will be deleted.

Comment: @Bart and I want to delete my stackexchange then will it delete my stackoverflow account also ?

Comment: @Williams the page you see [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/2268477/williams) is not a real profile or account, it's just a "portal" to your real accounts over the network. What Anna removed is your real profile on http://stackexchange.com/ so you now can't log in there. Hope it's clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I delete my StackExchange account then Will it delete my all account like stack overflow, meta.stackoverflow ??

We'll delete whatever accounts you want us to delete. If you want to remove all your site profiles, just let us know. (And otherwise follow the [instructions in the help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account).)

Deleting your Stack Exchange *website profile* isn't the same as deleting all your individual site profiles.

> I want this because system is buggy and opening account of someone else automatically that is completely wrong and made me frustrated

Err, wait. What. That's not how the system's supposed to work. Are you using a shared computer, by any chance? You're not supposed to end up in someone else's account under any normal circumstances.

Comment: Yes Please delete my all accounts stackexchange also but not stackoverflow

Comment: @Williams I marked your profiles (except Stack Overflow) for deletion. They will be removed in 24 hours. If you change your mind, you can cancel that at any time before that by going to your site profiles and clicking "cancel". (If you do change your mind, you have to cancel each deletion individually.)

Comment: Thank you but how this big system is working badly that increased my frustration, opening other account who have much reputation at all. This is my reason to delete all, might I will delete my stackoverflow also if I find this issue persist

Comment: @Williams I'm still not sure what issue you're seeing. Can you walk me through what happens when you sign in?

Comment: When I sign in to my account [stackoverflow] then it opens my account but after sometime when I go to metastackoverflow and stackexchange then it open the account of someone else, that I can misuse of it but I am not and dont want to do so

Comment: @Williams Wow. That really shouldn't be happening. Are you on a shared computer or are you the only person using the machine you sign in from?

Comment: I am only the person, nobody shared

Comment: If this happens bug might other can access my account also without sign in etc

Comment: I see you have marked my account for deletion, but you left this https://stackexchange.com/users/2268477/williams , please delete this also but not stackoverflow

Comment: @Williams Hrm. I don't see any unauthorized accesses on your account (or at least, no accesses from unusual IPs). I've also never heard of what you're describing happening outside of our dev tier where it's sort of expected and it's now locked down to employees only. If you have the profile links to the accounts you signed into when visiting meta, that'd be helpful. In the meantime, I removed your stackexchange.com profile as well (note that it's not delayed by 24 hours, so that deletion was immediate).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/720/discussion-between-williams-and-anna-lear)

Comment: @Anna is it cached somehow? I [can still see his network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/2268477/williams).

Comment: @Williams Take a look in Anna's profile. It's a "she", but yeah, something is weird here on many levels.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes still buggy, she failed to remove it stackexchange.com/users/2268477/williams

Comment: @Williams I removed your profile *on* stackexchange.com, but your network profile stays alive for as long as you have profiles on individual Q&A sites. It's a thing that holds them all together and associated with you, so there's no way to remove it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard See my comment above. Welcome to one of the wonderful quirks of our account/profile system. :)

Comment: @Anna so you removed something that nobody can see? Hope you understand why I'm very confused... anyway since the OP here wants to remove his network profile, think it's better to explain to him why it's not possible. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh no, you *can* see it... right up until it's deleted. It's ... yeah.

Comment: @Anna I [tried to explain](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228987/does-deleting-a-stack-exchange-account-delete-all-accounts-using-that-openid/228989?noredirect=1#comment751361_228987), hope he will understand.